# how quick read 25k small txt file content with python

Tags: python, performance, file

i download many html store in os,now get their content ,and extract data what i need to persistence to mysql,
i use the traditional load file one by one ,it's not efficant cost nealy 8 mins.

any advice is welcome

```
g_fields=[
 'name',
 'price',
 'productid',
 'site',
 'link',
 'smallImage',
 'bigImage',
 'description',
 'createdOn',
 'modifiedOn',
 'size',
 'weight',
 'wrap',
 'material',
 'packagingCount',
 'stock',
 'location',
 'popularity',
 'inStock',
 'categories',
]   @cost_time
def batch_xml2csv():
    "批量将xml导入到一个csv文件中"
    delete(g_xml2csv_file)
    f=open(g_xml2csv_file,"a")
    import os.path
    import mmap
    for file in glob.glob(g_filter):
    print "读入%s"%file
    ff=open(file,"r+")
    size=os.path.getsize(file)
    data=mmap.mmap(ff.fileno(),size)
    s=pq(data.read(size))
    data.close()
    ff.close()
    #s=pq(open(file,"r").read())
    line=[]
    for field in g_fields:
        r=s("field[@name='%s']"%field).text()
        if r is None:
            line.append("\N")
        else:
            line.append('"%s"'%r.replace('"','\"'))
    f.write(",".join(line)+"\n")
    f.close()
    print "done!"
```

i tried mmap,it seems didn't work well

Comment: @mlzboy : Code and profiling data would help.

Comment: What is the size of the average and largest 'small text file'?

Comment: Maybe you could put the zipped directory somewhere for download to test it out to help you, I do not understand where g_fields produce something out of the data and what pq is doing (priority queue?)

Comment: @spenthil from 491 bytes to 27kb,all data is extract from webpage

Comment: @Tony Veijalainen from pyquery import PyQuery as pq,i use pyquery parser xml data,g_fields is collect of cloumn name,i combine a csv for bulk insert to mysql

Comment: Hard to tell from the code provided whether the process is I/O or process bound. What is the average file size? What is `pq` in the statement `s=pq(data.read(size))`?

Comment: @martineau from 481 bytes to 27kb,pq is alias of pyquery package for xml parser

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you've got 25,000 text files on disk, 'you're doing it wrong'. Depending on how you store them on disk, the slowness could literally be seeking on disk to find the files.

If you've got 25,0000 of *anything* it'll be faster if you put it in a database with an intelligent index -- even if you make the index field the filename it'll be faster.

If you have multiple directories that descend N levels deep, a database would still be faster.

Comment: i store files on single directory

Comment: 25k files in one directory will take a long time to list no matter how you slice it. To give you an example, I wrote a script that generated N number files with between 0 and 65 kbytes of data. Running simply 'ls -l' took 0.021 seconds @ 1000 files, 0.199s for 10,000 files, and a whopping 0.487 seconds (half a second!) for 25,000 files. That's worst case scenario of course, but randomly picking files out of this list still means having to traverse the btree _and_ compete with other applications that're using the filesystem for reads and writes.

Comment: Whoops. I understand your problem a bit better now.. Whatever is producing these files should instead be writing directly to a database than using an intermediary file _before_ you write it to the database. If you're parsing through HTML consider writing your spider code in Python so it can do everything at once. Alternatively, use a tiered directory system so you can break up the chunks of files into more manageable parts. i.e. root/a/aa/aardvark.html, root/c/ch/chiapet.html ..

Comment: Why is this the accepted answer? It doesn't answer the question. I get that DB's are preferable. But if you've got the files from somewhere else, what's the fastest way to read them in Python.

Comment: Sometimes you don't have a choice - the data set was prepared in that format by an external source, and you have to deal with it as is.

Answer (score 0):

You can scan the files while downloading them in multiple threads if you use [scrapy](http://doc.scrapy.org).

Answer (score 0):

If algorith is correct, using the **psyco** module can sometimes help quite a lot. It does not however work with Python 2.7 or Python 3+